# Добавить в базу MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, циклы, form

У меня есть форма с циклом и обработчик на php.

```
<? if (isset($group)){$n = 1; $n2 = 1; $date = date('Y-m-d');?>
  <form class="inputs" action="adds?name=yoqlama" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="date" name="date" value="<?=$date;?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="idteacher" value="<?=$row3['idteacher'];?>">
  <?do{ ?>
  <div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="idpupil" value="<?=$row2['id'];?>" id="check<?=$n++;?>" checked><label for="check<?=$n2++;?>"><?=$row2['surname']." ".$row2['name'];?></label>
  </div>
  <?}while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getpupils));?>
  <button>Saqlash</button>
  </form>
<?}?>


if(isset($_POST['idpupil']))    {$idpupil = $_POST['idpupil'];}
if(isset($_POST['date']))       {$date = $_POST['date'];}
if(isset($_POST['idteacher']))  {$idteacher = $_POST['idteacher'];}
$come = 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($idpupil); $i++) {
        $arr = [];
        array_push($arr, $idpupil[$i],$date,$come,$idteacher);
        for ($k = 0; $k < 5; $k++) {
            array_push($arr, $result["results"][$k]['url']); 
        $query = "INSERT INTO yoqlama (idpupil,date,come,teacher) VALUES (NULL, $arr[1]','$arr[2]','$arr[3]','$arr[4]')";
        }
        print_r($arr);
        array_push($arr2, $arr);
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Но не работает: выдаёт ошибку и ничего не добавляет в базу:

> Warning: mysqli_query():
>
> Empty query in D:\Software\OSPanel\domains\hisobkitob.uz\admin\manager\add\adds.php on line 179

Comment: Судя по ошибке, цикл for у вас не отработал ни одного раза, поэтому переменная $query пустая.

Comment: как исправит это...

Comment: Проверяйте что у вас приходит в переменные по которым цикл.